# Add a scala file into parent package

Tags: scala, intellij-14

I am in this situation:

[image]

The package "vu.co.kaiyin.clipboard" has been created and has a package object in it. Now I want to add a new scala file in the package "vu.co.kaiyin". How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it on scala folder. Just add `vu.co.kaiyin.new_package` there - putting all  path.